# I get some error with sudo apt update,about git pub key

Tags: apt

fazil@acer:~$ sudo apt update
W: GPG error: https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C99B11DEB97541F0
E: The repository 'https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS